# For loop still working when boolean expression is false

Tags: java, for-loop, debugging

I wrote a nested loop. The weird thing is: the second loop still enters the statement when the condition is false and I don't know why.

```
int[] g = {1,2};
int[] s = {1,2,3};

for(int i=0;i<s.length;){
    for(int j=0;j<g.length&&i<s.length;){
        if(s[i]>=g[j]){
            i++;
            j++;
        }else{
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the inner loop to break when `j==g.length`, which is when `j == 2`. But what actually happens is, when `j==2`, the inner loop will jump to

```
...
else{
  i++;
}
```

Comment: I stepped through your code in a debugger, was unable to see the inner loop run while j was 2.

Comment: "when j==2, the inner loop will..." throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in `if (... >= g[j])` (assuming `g.length==2` and that the inner loop is not terminating)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger It won't and what OP describes happens, but not like they describe it. The `else` branch isn't actually executed, but the debugger will still highlight it, before jumping back to the outer `for` loop. That seems to be a problem with the javac compiler (I guess azurefrog uses Eclipse that's why he's unable to reproduce it). This has also been reported to IntelliJ (the IDE I use) several times, but they can't fix issues from the Java compiler: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-8021

Comment: @Tom question does not mention neither debugging nor IntelliJ - my comment is thus based on standard Java

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I mentioned the issue being the javac compiler, haven't I?

Comment: I see the problem now: it is debugging - "the inner loop will jump to" no, the debugger is *showing* the last line of the block. This happens because the end of the inner loop/continuation of outer loop (bytecode `goto`) has no line number information, so the debugger shows the previous known line which happens to be the last line of the `else` block (`i` will not be incremented if stepping)

Comment: confirmed, it is the `javac` compiler (and debugger) - Eclipse adds an additional line number information for the bytecode after the inner loop; `javac` is missing that. So every time the inner loop is terminated, the debugger *jumps* to the last statement of the loop (which is not executed, it's just visualization)

Answer (score 1):

How do you know its going to the else part? The inner loop will always stop when `j<g.length` condition will fail, which is  j=2.

Try putting in System.out.println() statements or debugger to check the flow.